# azure data factory - convert single value output from query into json

Tags: azure-data-factory

In azure data factory, I am getting a single record back from a database.
I need to take one column from this and pass it to a web call body.

The body takes data in this format:

["cdd-lm-54"]

I have tried multiple expressions but none of them work. appreciate any advice on how to perform this.

The data returned from the database looks like this:

```
 "value": [
        {
            "RowNumber": 1,
            "Tag": "cdd-lm-54",
            "Val1": "val 1",
            "Val2": "val b",
            "LastSyncDateTime": "2022-07-26T13:14:28Z",
            "LastTimeModified": "2021-07-28T10:33:47.7Z"
        }
    ]
```

The below expressions are the closest i have gotten, they output the data as i expect it to be but the web call still rejects it:

@concat('[','"',pipeline().parameters.DeviceRecord[0]['Tag'], '"',']')
[image]

@concat('[','''',pipeline().parameters.DeviceRecord[0]['Tag'], '''',']')
[image]

Odd thing is if i paste the exact value from ADF into postman, it works.

is adf doing something odd to the body?

Comment: why not using the Array method? like so array('cdd-lm-54')

Comment: did you try a derived column and then send it to a rest service? i think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

> Odd thing is if I paste the exact value from ADF into postman, it works.

The reason behind this is that the value that you take from the value and give it as `["cdd-lm-54"]`, it indicates that the body accepts an array containing required string.

- Using `@concat()` to build `["cdd-lm-54"]` will return a just a string, which is not the required data that the body accepts.
- Instead use the following dynamic content

```
@array(pipeline().parameters.DeviceRecord[0]['Tag'])
```

- The above returns an array containing the required value.
  [image]